# SQLAlchemy query slow with datetime type objects

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a Flask API with SQLAlchemy interfacing a PostgreSQL database.
One of the requests queries a table in a way similar to the following:

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE updated_at >= %(updates_from)s AND updated_at <= %(updates_to)s`

Pseudo-code of the query to illustrate the problem:

```
import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, sql

db_engine = create_engine("postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/mydb")
db_connection = db_engine.connect()

d_updates_from = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0)
d_updates_to = datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 20, 17, 47)

sql_command = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE updated_at >= :updates_from AND updated_at <= :updates_to"

cur = db_connection.execute(
    sql.text(sql_command),
    updates_from=d_updates_from,
    updates_to=d_updates_to
)
```

In the database, the `updates_from` and `updates_to` are both of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

By invoking the query directly from `psql` I acquired a response in less than a second. However, when queried via SQLAlchemy, it took about 20 s.

The SQLAlchemy query time was reduced to below a second by converting the Python `datetime` objects into ISO 8601 strings. This was done by calling `.isoformat()` on them before passing them to `db_connection.execute()`. Pseudo-code to illustrate the work-around:

```
cur = db_connection.execute(
    sql.text(sql_command),
    updates_from=d_updates_from.isoformat(),
    updates_to=d_updates_to.isoformat()
)
```

A few questions:

1. Why is there close to 100x difference in query speed when supplying SQLAlchemy `execute()` with `datetime` versus ISO 8601 string?
2. Is this behaviour documented somewhere?

I'm using

- sqlalchemy=1.3.3=py36h7b6447c_0
- psycopg2=2.7.6.1=py36h1ba5d50_0
- PostgreSQL 11.1

**Edit:** As suggested in the comments, I tried to produce a minimum working example of the issue. While there is a difference in speed, it is just a few times. Moreover, since the set of columns is completely different, it might be that the minimum working example showcases a different issue altogether.

Bash script to create `testdb` with a couple of tables and a view:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

sudo -u postgres psql -c "DROP DATABASE testdb;"
sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE DATABASE testdb;"

geometry="0106000020BE0B000001000000010300000001000000040000001806811505E71B412085EBE1B57358419A1C5A64A9E51B418A6CE7EBC4735841D64F8D17D2E71B41656666AEE67358411806811505E71B412085EBE1B5735841"

num=1000

sudo -u postgres psql -d testdb <<EOF
CREATE EXTENSION postgis; 

CREATE TABLE foreign1(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, geom GEOMETRY(MultiPolygon,3006));
INSERT INTO foreign1 (geom) SELECT '${geometry}' FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, ${num}) s(i);

CREATE TABLE data(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, f_id INTEGER REFERENCES foreign1(id), updated_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE);
INSERT INTO data (f_id, updated_at) SELECT i, DATE '2018-01-01' + i FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, ${num}) s(i);

CREATE VIEW v1 AS SELECT d.f_id, d.updated_at, f.geom FROM data d LEFT JOIN foreign1 f ON d.f_id = f.id;
GRANT SELECT ON v1 TO public;
EOF
```

Python script to perform the queries and measure the timing:

```py
import time
import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, sql


def query(db_connection, sql_command, d_updates_from, d_updates_to):
    t_start = time.time()
    # Query with substituted timestamps.
    cur = db_connection.execute(
        sql.text(sql_command),
        updates_from=d_updates_from,
        updates_to=d_updates_to
    )
    t_end = time.time()

    # EXPLAIN the query
    cur = db_connection.execute(
        sql.text("EXPLAIN ANALYZE " + sql_command),
        updates_from=d_updates_from,
        updates_to=d_updates_to
    )
    explain_str = ""
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        explain_str += row[0] + "\n"

    # Return resulting dataframe, query execution time, query plan.
    return (t_end - t_start), explain_str

# Connect to the database
db_engine = create_engine("postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb")
db_connection = db_engine.connect()
# Timestamp range to query.
d_updates_from = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0)
d_updates_to = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0)
# Template of the query.
sql_command = "SELECT * FROM v1 WHERE updated_at >= :updates_from AND updated_at <= :updates_to;"

# Query with datetime objects.
t_variant1, explain_str1 = query(db_connection, sql_command, d_updates_from, d_updates_to)

# Query with ISO 8601 strings instead of datetime objects.
t_variant2, explain_str2 = query(db_connection, sql_command, d_updates_from.isoformat(), d_updates_to.isoformat())

print("Took {:.6f} s with datetime, {:.6f} s with ISO 8601 string. ({:.2f}x difference)".format(t_variant1, t_variant2, t_variant1 / t_variant2))
print("\nExplain with datetime:\n{}\n\nExplain with ISO 8601 string:\n{}".format(explain_str1, explain_str2))
```

Example output:

```
Took 0.012409 s with datetime, 0.002292 s with ISO 8601 string. (5.41x difference)

Explain with datetime:
Hash Left Join  (cost=41.50..64.43 rows=730 width=124) (actual time=0.287..0.682 rows=730 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (d.f_id = f.id)
  ->  Seq Scan on data d  (cost=0.00..21.00 rows=730 width=12) (actual time=0.010..0.272 rows=730 loops=1)
        Filter: ((updated_at >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (updated_at <= '2020-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 270
  ->  Hash  (cost=29.00..29.00 rows=1000 width=116) (actual time=0.265..0.265 rows=1000 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 153kB
        ->  Seq Scan on foreign1 f  (cost=0.00..29.00 rows=1000 width=116) (actual time=0.004..0.131 rows=1000 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.285 ms
Execution Time: 0.729 ms


Explain with ISO 8601 string:
Hash Left Join  (cost=41.50..64.43 rows=730 width=124) (actual time=0.264..0.512 rows=730 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (d.f_id = f.id)
  ->  Seq Scan on data d  (cost=0.00..21.00 rows=730 width=12) (actual time=0.007..0.123 rows=730 loops=1)
        Filter: ((updated_at >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00+02'::timestamp with time zone) AND (updated_at <= '2020-01-01 00:00:00+02'::timestamp with time zone))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 270
  ->  Hash  (cost=29.00..29.00 rows=1000 width=116) (actual time=0.253..0.253 rows=1000 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 153kB
        ->  Seq Scan on foreign1 f  (cost=0.00..29.00 rows=1000 width=116) (actual time=0.003..0.123 rows=1000 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.115 ms
Execution Time: 0.548 ms
```

Comment: Somewhat instant using a fair amount of rows and `datetime` objects, or in other words cannot reproduce.

Comment: @IljaEverilä: Which package versions did you have? For me already 50 rows with 20 columns resulted in 20 s when using `datetime` objects.

Comment: The exact versions listed.

Comment: I did not consider it relevant but this issue was encountered on AWS.
So far I also have not been able to reproduce the issue on other machines with the same database - it always takes less than 100 ms.

Comment: Could you shed some light on your AWS setup?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL which includes constraints & indexes & base table initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results. (Constraints, indexes & plans are critical to performance.) PS Clarify via edits, not comments.